# Is there a way to have transition only on a single CSS change?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to rotate and move a square (`<img>`) to a specific mouse click on screen.

I want the rotation to happen instantly, but the movement happen linearly, over a duration of time (distance/speed).

However, I can't find a way to separate these two actions. I set the img rotation first and afterwards set it's `style.left/top` with a `style.transitionDuration`, but the rotation ends up with a duration as well.

Is there a way to only include the `transitionDuration` on the change of `left` and `top`, thus excluding it from the rotation?

Comment: Do you want to first rotate and then move or you want both simultaneously?

Comment: Might've not been very clear yea, I want it to happen simultaneously. It needs to rotate towards the mouse click, and move towards the mouse click as well.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-panna-qbnkut?file=/index.html

Do you want like this?

Comment: I'm not clear exactly what is required as your comment seems different from the text in the question (where you use the word 'simultaneously'). Do you want the rotation to happen instantaneously or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly specify which properties to transition. If you want the rotation to be instant, just omit it from the transition:

```js
document.querySelector('img')
  .addEventListener('click',
  ({target}) => target.classList.toggle('clicked')
);
```

```css
img {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: top 1s ease, left 1s ease;
}

.clicked {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="//placekitten.com/100" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the `transition` property.

```
img.style.transition = 'top 1s linear, left 1s linear';
```

Now the only transitions applied are for both `top` and `left`.